# Como pasar variables por enlace y metodo GET con rutas resource Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una duda, estoy trabajando en un proyecto y necesito enviar una variable que contiene un ID a mi metodo create o que simplemente me pase la url, para ello estoy utilizando rutas de tipo resource:

```
Route::resource('encuestaspy/participar', 'Users\RespuestaController');
```

Esta es mi vista

```
@foreach ($preguntas as $pregunta)
        @if($pregunta->user_id == $empresa->id)
            @if($pregunta->estado == 1 )

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                    <div style="padding: 10px;"></div>
                      //qui es donde quiero mandar mi variable con cierto ID.
                    <a href="{{url('encuestaspy/participar/create'.$pregunta->pregunta_id)}}">
                        @if(empty($pregunta->foto))
                            <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" width="300" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="">
                        @else
                            <img id="imagen" class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="{{asset('imagenes/encuestas/'.$pregunta->foto)}}" width="300" alt="">
                        @endif
                    </a>
                    <p class="text-center">{{$pregunta->titulo}}</p>
                    @if ($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') > $pregunta->fecha_finalizacion)
                        <p style="color:#FF0000"; class="text-center">Encuesta finalizada</p>
                    @endif
                    <p class="text-center"><b>Culmina el:</b>{{$pregunta->fecha_finalizacion}}</p>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

este es el metodo de mi controlador, que por ahora solo retorna una vista pues todavia no escribo nada porque necesito el id para empezar

```
public function create()
{
    //
    return view('welcome');
}
```

OJO: Ya se que se puede enviar por rutas de tipo GET las variables que necesito, pero yo preciso que sean con rutas de tipos RESOURCE por pedido de mi jefe :(

Comment: que versión de laravel?

Comment: laravel 5.6....

Comment: Encontré esto en la documentación, creo que soluciona tu problema: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo el `resource` ya posee rutas preestablecidas y no creo que puedas usar `encuestaspy/participar/create/{id}`. Lo que puedes hacer es pasarle por método GET el identificador en tu vista `{{ url('encuestaspy/participar/create?id'.$pregunta->pregunta_id) }}` de tal manera que puedas recibir de la siguiente forma en tu controlador.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    //
}
```

Comment: probe como me dijiste @Silvio Baez y me funciono genial! no tenia conexión por eso te respondo recien!